# how to run docker image only on certain machines?

Tags: docker

i,m trying to create a docker image which can be executed only via certain people.
is there a way to make sure that your docker image can only be executed on a
certain machine and if copied it wont run on any other cluster or node?
if docker cannot provide such feature is it possible doing it with Kubernetes or Openshift?

Comment: Run a private Docker registry accessible only to the people you want?

Comment: I agree - you can do so only by limiting the access to the image. So if you are aiming at prohibiting customers from redistributing your image: no, you are at a loss at the docker level. Try a mechanism to let customers enter their license into some interface after first creation of a data volume on the docker host.